# R Loop through array of split strings comapring each rows last word

Tags: r, for-loop, split

I have a column called behaviours path that I split into a list of words. How do I iterate through each list row comparing current row last value with the next rows last value?

This is my original column before splitting

```
VisualDNA > VisualDNA > TV Audiences > Media 
Consumption > TV > Light

VisualDNA > VisualDNA > TV Audiences > Media 
Consumption > TV > Medium
```

I first spilt the column by character ">"

```
[[906]]
[1] "VisualDNA "          " VisualDNA "         
" TV Audiences "      " Media Consumption "
[5] " TV "                " Light"             

[[907]]
[1] "VisualDNA "          " VisualDNA "         
" TV Audiences "      " Media Consumption "
[5] " TV "                " Medium"            


VisualDNA > VisualDNA 100.00000

VisualDNA > VisualDNA > Auto 87.11140

Auto Owner
VisualDNA > VisualDNA > Auto > Auto Owner 21.11940

Budget
VisualDNA > VisualDNA > Auto > Budget 33.50590

Average
VisualDNA > VisualDNA > Auto > Budget > Average  9.11659

VisualDNA > VisualDNA > Auto > Budget > Good 17.97330

VisualDNA > VisualDNA > Auto > Budget > High 7.85650
```

The last word is the behaviour and the second and third words should be grouped then calculating the average for each value in adjacent column called values.

Comment: What is the comparison you want to make?  What's your desired output?

Comment: At the end of the first line, we see `Media` followed by appears to be a newline, and then more content.  Does your text have newlines in it?  Or, is `Consumption` the start of the next line?

Comment: Tim medium is the last word

Comment: andrew_reece I want to group nested words then calculate each rows percentage

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to identify word number from the behaviors path by expanding data frame to have each work in a separate row.

A `tidyr::separate_rows` based solution can be as:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  separate_rows(Behaviours_path, sep="\\s+>\\s+") %>%
  group_by(rn) %>%
  mutate(WordNumber = paste("Word",row_number(),sep="_"))

# # A tibble: 12 x 4
# # Groups: rn [2]
# Value    rn Behaviours_path   WordNumber
# <int> <int> <chr>             <chr>     
#   1   100     1 VisualDNA         Word_1    
# 2   100     1 VisualDNA         Word_2    
# 3   100     1 TV Audiences      Word_3    
# 4   100     1 Media Consumption Word_4    
# 5   100     1 TV                Word_5    
# 6   100     1 Light             Word_6    
# 7    80     2 VisualDNA         Word_1    
# 8    80     2 VisualDNA         Word_2    
# 9    80     2 TV Audiences      Word_3    
# 10    80     2 Media Consumption Word_4    
# 11    80     2 TV                Word_5    
# 12    80     2 Medium            Word_6
```

**Data:** Since, OP hasnt provided full data.frame hence I created a sample data frame which represents `Behaviours_path` column based on description provided by OP. Other details are dummy.

```
df <- read.table(text = 
"Behaviours_path      Value
'VisualDNA > VisualDNA > TV Audiences > Media Consumption > TV > Light' 100
'VisualDNA > VisualDNA > TV Audiences > Media Consumption > TV > Medium' 80",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: How do I group last word by second and third last words by each row in column Behaviours Path?